# Calculating the pH of a sodium phosphate solution

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, ph

I have the following question in a chemistry homework:

> Calculate the $\mathrm{pH}$ of a solution made by dissolving $\pu{113 g}$ of sodium phosphate in enough water to make a solution with a final volume of $\pu{475 mL}$. Find the equilibrium concentration of all species present in this solution.

It shouldn't be that hard of a problem, but my teacher really doesn't explain well at a distance (with the COVID-19 situation). I have found that it dissociates into $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{H3PO4}$ when in water:
$$\ce{Na3PO4(s) + 3H2O(l) → 3NaOH(aq) + H3PO4(aq)}$$

But I don't really know what to do next...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do not think it can be strongly acidic and strongly alkalic at the same time, do you ? Google 3 equilibrium dissociation reactions of phosphoric acid.

Comment: No of course not, but if $Na_3PO_4$ dissociates and just the $PO_4$ ion reacts with water, it could make $HPO_4$, $H_2PO_4$ or $H_3PO_4$, right?

Comment: Yes, right, but you need to quantify that. Technote: If you use mhchem MathJax extension, you can Write formulas as \$\ce{H3PO4}\$ what will look like $\ce{H3PO4}$

Comment: See [phosphoric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphoric_acid) section acidic properties.

Comment: Sorry, it is not an easy problem. If she really means "find the equilibrium concentration of all species present in this solution."

Comment: It can be approximated as calculation of pH for a PO4^3h base with pKb = 14 - pKa3, and from that pH to calculate ratios of phosphate forms, as the pKax are far enough from each other.

Comment: 113 g of solute in 475 mL of solutions is far from a dilute, near-ideal solution. [Ionic strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_strength) will surely not be negligible.